# Can anyone explain how to print all keys if two keys are same but with different values?

Tags: string, perl, hash

In this code two keys "39" are same name but different values , I want to print both keys

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my %studentnames = ( 
14 => Martha, 
27 =>Vivek, 
31 =>Era, 
16 =>Marty, 
25 =>Jason, 
29 =>Socrates, 
19 =>Uri, 
39 =>Nitin , 
39 =>Plato, 
); 

foreach my $name (sort keys %studentnames) 
{ 
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $studentnames{$name};
}
```

I am getting error.

```
Bareword "Martha" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Vivek" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Era" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Marty" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Jason" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Socrates" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Uri" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Nitin" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
Bareword "Plato" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /home/9945b48d30946ed2641d9778b42cb182.pl line 10.
```

Expected Output

```
14   Martha
27   Vivek 
31   Era
16   Marty 
25   Jason 
29   Socrates 
19   Uri
39   Nitin 
39   Plato
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: The suggestion to use a hash like this was a bad one. You should not encourage more people to solve the question on this premise. For example, in a hash a number `3`, `3.0` and `03` will all be considered different, even though they are numerically the same. What you have created here is an XY-problem.

Comment: The sorted expected output is not exactly clear. Is your goal to sort by student numbers, then by student names? In this case, why do you expect `16   Marty`  to be sorted **after** `31   Era`? Also, are the names unique? Or is the combination of number **and** name unique? If nothing is unique by itself or in combination, the hash is not the right data structure, as others have mentioned, and you need an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kinda close:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::Hash::MultiValueOrdered;

tie my %studentnames, 'Tie::Hash::MultiValueOrdered';
%studentnames = (
    14 => 'Martha',
    27 => 'Vivek',
    31 => 'Era',
    16 => 'Marty',
    25 => 'Jason',
    29 => 'Socrates',
    19 => 'Uri',
    39 => 'Nitin',
    39 => 'Plato',
); 

tied(%studentnames)->fetch_list;

while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %studentnames ) {
    print "$key => @$value\n";
}
```

But really you want to use a different data structure. Perhaps an array of arrayrefs?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @students = (
    [ 14 => 'Martha'   ],
    [ 27 => 'Vivek'    ],
    [ 31 => 'Era'      ],
    [ 16 => 'Marty'    ],
    [ 25 => 'Jason'    ],
    [ 29 => 'Socrates' ],
    [ 19 => 'Uri'      ],
    [ 39 => 'Nitin'    ],
    [ 39 => 'Plato'    ],
); 

for my $student ( @students ) {
    my ( $num, $name ) = @$student;
    print "$num => $name\n";
}
```

Or an array of hashrefs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @students = (
    { num => 14 , name => 'Martha'   },
    { num => 27 , name => 'Vivek'    },
    { num => 31 , name => 'Era'      },
    { num => 16 , name => 'Marty'    },
    { num => 25 , name => 'Jason'    },
    { num => 29 , name => 'Socrates' },
    { num => 19 , name => 'Uri'      },
    { num => 39 , name => 'Nitin'    },
    { num => 39 , name => 'Plato'    },
); 

for my $student ( @students ) {
    print "$student->{num} => $student->{name}\n";
}
```

Or a hash of arrayrefs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %students = (
    14 => [ 'Martha'   ],
    27 => [ 'Vivek'    ],
    31 => [ 'Era'      ],
    16 => [ 'Marty'    ],
    25 => [ 'Jason'    ],
    29 => [ 'Socrates' ],
    19 => [ 'Uri'      ],
    39 => [ 'Nitin', 'Plato' ],
); 

for my $key ( sort keys %students ) {
    for my $name ( @{$students{$key}} ) {
        print "$key => $name\n";
    }
}
```

Or you could even create a lightweight "person" class.

```
use Z;

my $Person = class sub {
    has num  => ( type => PositiveInt );
    has name => ( type => NonEmptyStr );
};

my @students = (
    $Person->new( num => 14, name => 'Marta'    ),
    $Person->new( num => 27, name => 'Vivek'    ),
    $Person->new( num => 31, name => 'Era'      ),
    $Person->new( num => 16, name => 'Marty'    ),
    $Person->new( num => 25, name => 'Jason'    ),
    $Person->new( num => 29, name => 'Socrates' ),
    $Person->new( num => 19, name => 'Uri'      ),
    $Person->new( num => 39, name => 'Nitin'    ),
    $Person->new( num => 39, name => 'Plato'    ),
); 

for my $student ( @students ) {
    printf "%s => %s\n", $student->num, $student->name;
}
```

There's a lot of ways to go about solving this, but a single flat hash of strings is probably not one of them.

Comment: You've been busy! That Z thing looks fun.

Comment: `my @students = map { $Person->new( ... ) } ...;` :)

Answer (score 9):

Two keys *cannot* be the same. One will overwrite the other. If you want to have multiple values for one key then you need to design your data structure to support that (e.g. by having the value be an arrayref).

Your error messages are unrelated to that problem (you forgot to put quotes around your string values).

Answer (score 4):

As a starter: the hash values are strings, so they need to be quoted. This is why you are getting a syntax error:

```
my %studentnames = ( 
    14 => 'Martha', 
    27 => 'Vivek', 
    31 => 'Era', 
    ... 
);
```

Then: there is a misconception of what a Perl hash is. Each key in the hash must be unique. Perl tolerates declaring a hash with duplicate keys, but under the hood, only the last value of each key is retained.

So this:

```
my %studentnames = ( 
    14 => 'Martha', 
    39 => 'Nitin', 
    39 => 'Plato' 
);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
my %studentnames = ( 
    14 => 'Martha', 
    39 => 'Plato' 
);
```

Another way to see it is to put the assignments in separate instructions:

```
my %studentnames;
$studentnames{14} = 'Martha';
$studentnames{39} = 'Nitin';
$studentnames{39} = 'Plato';

print $studentnames{39}, "\n";
# Plato
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to excellent answers provided by others, and explanations of how to make the code work (e.g., quote the names, etc), here is another simple solution. I assume that the student names are unique (as they indeed appear in your example). In this case, use the *reverse* of your hash. That is, change it from the mapping of number to name to the mapping of name to number. Sort the hash by values (student numbers) numerically, then by keys (student names) ASCIIbetically. This is my guess as to one possible way of sorting that makes intuitive sense to the user.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %student_name_to_num =
    reverse ( 
        14 => 'Martha', 
        27 => 'Vivek', 
        31 => 'Era', 
        16 => 'Marty', 
        25 => 'Jason', 
        29 => 'Socrates', 
        19 => 'Uri', 
        39 => 'Nitin', 
        39 => 'Plato', 
    ); 

foreach my $name ( sort {
    $student_name_to_num{$a} <=> $student_name_to_num{$b} ||
        $a cmp $b
} keys %student_name_to_num ) { 
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $student_name_to_num{$name}, $name;
}
```

Output:

```
14       Martha
16       Marty
19       Uri
25       Jason
27       Vivek
29       Socrates
31       Era
39       Nitin
39       Plato
```

---

Note that the order of the records is different from the sorted order you showed. But it is not clear how you want the records to be sorted (see also my comment under the question).